# error in building a simple user interface in Android using XML (The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed)

Tags: xml, android-layout

I'm learning how to develop applications using Android.

This is the first lesson of building a simple user interface and facing the error
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

here is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientatio="horizonatal"


    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_widthe="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send">
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

the lesson is on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though the LinearLayout element is missing its closing angle bracket. There also appear to be a couple of typos in the final attribute name and value.

Try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">
```

You've also forgotten to close your EditText element and there's a typo in 'width'. Try:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```